# Shopify error Uncaught exception 'ShopifyApiException' with message 'Not Implemented' when trying to create discount hook

Tags: php, hook, shopify, discount

I am trying to create discount coupon using hook but I am getting this error below.

> Uncaught exception 'ShopifyApiException' with message 'Not Implemented'

Answer (score 0):

Support for discount coupons is only avaialable in Shopify Plus.

If you have that then please post your code. Otherwise no one can help.